# Unable to run project after installing React-Native-firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I recently install `react-native-firebase` package with my react native project and follow all the necessary steps from [official](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup) documentation but after building my project its saying ##you attempted to use a firebase module thats not install on your android project by calling firebase.auth() ##

I tried:

1.delete my build file from from android/app folder and build again
2.update my Google Play Services and Google Repository

But they didn't work

my `build.gradle` file:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        ext {
            buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
            minSdkVersion = 16
            compileSdkVersion = 27
            targetSdkVersion = 26
            supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
        }
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
        }
    }


    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '4.6'
        distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
    }
```

and my `app/build.gradle` file:

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

    import com.android.build.OutputFile

    /**
    * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
    * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
    * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
    * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
    * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
    * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
    * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
    *
    * project.ext.react = [
    *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
    *
    *   // the entry file for bundle generation
    *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
    *
    *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
    *   bundleInDebug: false,
    *
    *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
    *   bundleInRelease: true,
    *
    *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
    *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
    *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
    *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
    *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
    *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
    *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
    *   // bundleInBeta: true,
    *
    *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
    *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
    *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
    *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
    *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
    *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
    *
    *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
    *   root: "../../",
    *
    *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
    *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
    *
    *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
    *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
    *
    *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
    *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
    *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
    *
    *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
    *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
    *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
    *
    *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
    *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
    *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
    *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
    *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
    *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
    *
    *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
    *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
    *
    *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
    *   extraPackagerArgs: []
    * ]
    */

    project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js"
    ]

    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

    /**
    * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
    *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
    *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
    * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
    * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
    * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
    */
    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

    /**
    * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
    */
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

    android {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.shohay"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
        splits {
            abi {
                reset()
                enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
                include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            }
        }
        // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
    }

    // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
    // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`screen shot` : [image-error](https://i.ibb.co/x1xRq2n/Capture.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: to use in v6: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage

In v5 (deprecated):
you are trying to use the Auth module without setting it up. Please refer to this to setup the auth:
https://v5.rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/getting-started

And similarly, if you want other firebase modules, you will have to include each one of them. Another suggestion is to use the firebase-starter-kit that comes with everything installed.

Comment: @Moshtaba Darzi no problem I'll update the link when i get home inshaAllah, meanwhile you can try looking for the module yourself, you get the idea :)

Comment: @Moshtaba Darzi I added the link for v6 and updated the old link

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue, when I run my project it showed this:

[image]

I added this code `import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;` in start of `MainApplication.java` and `new RNFirebaseAuthPackage()` in `getPackages()` function of same file. But when I added this code `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:x.x.x"` in `app gradle` it did not sync the gradle file and failed saying 'try again' (here x.x.x defines different versions tried by me). but when I tried 17.0.0 version, it worked fine. The reason is that you should search all the versions online and try one by one, this method always worked for me